# Подключение скриптов через cdn

Tags: wordpress

Нужно объединить js-скрипты в один для ускорения загрузки сайта, но скрипты подключаются через cdn в футере, а в футере есть только код подключения стилей. Откуда подключаются js-скрипты не понятно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно объединить такие скрипты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипты подключаются в function.php темы и файлах плагинов посредством вызова wp_enqueue_script(). Сводить все это хозяйство вместе - работа тяжелая и неблагодарная. Изменения в плагинах слетят при первом же обновлении.

Поставьте плагин [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) и не мучайтесь.